# Python Out of memory in range

Tags: python, memory, stream

I have the following problem:

```
chunks = []

#He we have an out of memory
for i in range(chunks_count):
    chunk_info = {'offset': struct.unpack('<I', stream_file.read(int_length))[0],
                  'length': struct.unpack('<I', stream_file.read(int_length))[0]}
    chunks.append(chunk_info)
```

The above code runs out of memory, which is quite reasonable with `chunk_size` being 2315780096. Is there a better way to write this piece of code not to run out of memory?

Comment: In Python 2 you can use `xrange` instead.  In Python 3 `range` already returns a generator-like object.  Or is the memory error in `chunks.append`?

Comment: What is `chunk_size`?  Do you mean `chunks_count`?  Or `int_length`?

Comment: Do you have enough memory to represent 2315780096 of *anything*, much less dictionaries in an array?

Comment: Assuming the majority of memory is used for the content `chucks` list, what are you then doing with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems likely that for Python 2

```
chunks = [
    {
        'offset': struct.unpack('<I', stream_file.read(int_length))[0],
        'length': struct.unpack('<I', stream_file.read(int_length))[0]
    }
    for _ in xrange(chunks_count)
]
```

For Python 3, this might be a good solution.

```
chunks = [
    {
        'offset': struct.unpack('<I', stream_file.read(int_length))[0],
        'length': struct.unpack('<I', stream_file.read(int_length))[0]
    }
    for _ in range(chunks_count)
]
```

But it seems like using a `namedtuple` would be even better, since they are more memory efficient than dicts, and your variables suggest you can use a fixed set of fields.

This would be something like for Python 2

```
import collections

ChunkInfo = collections.namedtuple('ChunkInfo', ['offset', 'length'])

chunks = [
    ChunkInfo(
        struct.unpack('<I', stream_file.read(int_length))[0],
        struct.unpack('<I', stream_file.read(int_length))[0])
    )
    for _ in xrange(chunks_count)
]
```

And this for Python 3

```
import collections

ChunkInfo = collections.namedtuple('ChunkInfo', ['offset', 'length'])

chunks = [
    ChunkInfo(
        struct.unpack('<I', stream_file.read(int_length))[0],
        struct.unpack('<I', stream_file.read(int_length))[0])
    )
    for _ in range(chunks_count)
]
```